# I am exporting text from a word document and nothing happens

Tags: vba, ms-word, export

I have a huge word file with many objects in different sizes seperated by commas. something like this:

eggs, bread, cheese
*water, candy, chocolate*
tissues, fish, meat
*juice, apples, oranges*
grapes, watermelon, peaches

imagine a file like that but a thousand times longer.
I want only the italic text (which, in the Word file, have a specific text size) , so I've created this VBA code to export each object in a new line to a txt file. the code seems to run fine, the only problem is that when it finishes to run, there's nothing in the txt file...

```
this is my code:
Sub tryIt()
    Dim findRange As Range
    Dim selctio As String
    Dim product As String
    Dim factory As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim replaced As String
    Dim count As Integer

    'opening a file to write to
    FilePath = "C:\Users\1romh\Desktop\qwert.txt"
    Open FilePath For Output As #3
    'looking for all texts that are size 7
    Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    findRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    findRange.Find.Font.Size = 7
    'for each text that is size 7...
    Do While findRange.Find.Execute(findtext:="") = True
        findRange.Select
        ''the problem might be in the next line as I'm not sure if I've done it right
        selectio = RangeSelected
        '...check how many times it has a comma...
        replaced = Replace(selectio, ",", "")
        count = Len(selectio) - Len(replaced)
        '...for each times it has a comma...
        For i = 1 To count + 1
        '...take the part before the comma...
        pos = InStr(",", selectio)
        product = Left(selctio, pos - 1)
        '...and print it, then delete the first object with his comma and do it again.
        selectio = Right(selectio, Len(product) + 1)

        Print #3, product
        Next i



        DoEvents
    Loop
    Close #3
    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
Sub FindItalic()
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content

    FilePath = "C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\qwert.txt"
    Open FilePath For Output As #3

    With oRng.Find
        ' to ensure that unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
        .ClearFormatting
        'You don't care what the text is
        .Text = ""
        'Find the italic text
        .Font.Italic = True
        'Loop for each match and set a color
        While .Execute
            MsgBox (oRng.Text)
            Print #3, oRng.Text

        Wend

    End With

    Close #3
End Sub
```

This is assuming that your commas are not in italic.

if they are also in italics, you can try to integrate your logic in this.